# *ngIf is adding elements instead of replaceing them

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-ng-if

My Code

```
<i *ngIf="!isFollowing" class="far fa-bell"></i>
<i *ngIf="isFollowing" class="fas fa-bell"></i>
```

Type of isFollowing is Boolean

Whenever I'm changing it to true or false it's showing the new element according to the expression but it is not removing the previous element but adding a new element to the DOM.
As a result, multiple icons are visible like in the image.

[Multiple Icons being Added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5YGo.jpg)

I believe change detection is detecting the change and adding a new DOM element but it's not updating the previous DOM Element.

Comment: `<i [class]="'fa-bell fa' + (isFollowing ? 's' : 'r')"></i>`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<i [ngClass]="{'far': !isFollowing, 'fas': isFollowing}"  class="fa-bell"> <i>
```

Comment: I was gonna accept this answer because this should have worked but it didn't. The icon stays the same even if the value of the boolean changes. I believe the problem is with something else which is breaking the page and thus the issue with change detection.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```html
<i *ngIf="!isFollowing; else follow" class="far fa-bell"></i>
<ng-template #follow><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></ng-template>
```

Comment: That should do exactly the same thing as OPs code does.

Comment: If the issue is with the change detection and one of the `*ngIf` beahving poorly, no. The `ng-template` relies on the condition of the first `*ngIf` : the code goes from two conditions to one.

Comment: Than the problem is with change detection and not two `ngIf` directives, so your code still does not solve the problem, only hides it. What do you mean `ngIf` is "behaving poorly"? That doesn't happen.

Comment: I didn't say it happens, the OP said it by stating the first DOM element was'nt being deleted. I too highly doubt it, I just gave my two cents on the matter (and upvoted the `ngClass` answer since I find it way more suited).

Comment: Didn't really help. Did the same thing as *ngIf i.e. adding to the DOM but not removing the previous. I believe the problem is more deep-rooted than just syntax.

Comment: @AbhijeetChakraborty in this case you should provide a [mcve] of the issue. 99% of the time, the issue comes from the developer, not the framework : if you provide a [mcve] we could help you resolve this issue, and if it's really a framework issue, then you should open a repository issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not you doing this with `ngClass`?

```
<i [ngClass]="{'fas fa-bell': isFollowing == true, 'far fa-bell': isFollowing == false}"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same issue, each of the suggested answers did not work. I haven't figured out why this was happening, but I solved it by wrapping the `i` tags in `span` tags and moving the `*ngIf` to the `span` tags like so:

```html
<span *ngIf="!isFollowing"><i class="far fa-bell"></i></span>
<span *ngIf="isFollowing"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></span>
```